# List file names in a folder matching a pattern, excluding file content

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am using the below to recursively list all files in a folder that contains the `$pattern`

```
Get-ChildItem $targetDir -recurse | Select-String -pattern "$pattern" | group path | select name
```

But it seems it both list files having the `$pattern` in its name and in its *content*, e.g. when I run the above where `$pattern="SAMPLE"` I get:

```
C:\tmp\config.include
C:\tmp\README.md
C:\tmp\specs\SAMPLE.data.nuspec
C:\tmp\specs\SAMPLE.Connection.nuspec
```

Now:

```
C:\tmp\config.include
C:\tmp\README.md
```

indeed contains the SAMPLE keywords/text but I don't care about that, I only need the command to list file names not file with content matching the pattern. What am I missing?

Based on the below answers I have also tried:

```
$targetDir="C:\tmp\"
Get-ChildItem $targetDir -recurse | where {$_.name -like "SAMPLE"} | group path | select name
```

and:

```
$targetDir="C:\tmp\"
Get-ChildItem $targetDir -recurse | where {$_.name -like "SAMPLE"} | select name
```

but it does not return any results.

Comment: My comment on the answer you took your edit from explains why that does not work.

Comment: You latest edit would only return files named literally "Sample". Use wildcards `"*sample*"`

Comment: You are right works when I do the pattern with "*sample*"

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) is doing what you told it to. Emphasis mine.

> The Select-String cmdlet searches for text and text patterns **in input strings and files**.

So if you are just looking to match with file names just use `-Filter` of `Get-ChildItem` or post process with `Where-Object`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter "*sample*"
```

That should return all files *and folders* that have sample in their name. If you just wanted files or directories you would be able to use the switches `-File` or `-Directory` to return those specific object types.

If your pattern is more complicated than a simple word then you might need to use `Where-Object` like in [Itchydon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44826025/3829407) with something like `-match` giving you access to regex.

---

The grouping logic in your code should be redundant since you are returning single files that all have unique paths. Therefore I have not included that here. If you just want the paths then you can pipe into `Select-Object -Expand FullName` or just `(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter "*sample*").Fullname`

Comment: for Get-ChildItem you can use shortcut "gci"

Comment: @devi You can use the shortcut, but I would advise against it because it reduces readability. Especially for people that are less experienced with Powershell.

Comment: works: Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Newfolder\  -Recurse  -Filter "*.json*" But I need the folder names containing json files. This doesn't work Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Newfolder\  -Recurse  -Filter "*.json*" -directory

Comment: @bomaboom That command returns all files matching your criteria. If you only want the folder names you need to request that from the resulting data. try piping to `select directory -unique`

Answer (score 19):

```
get-ChildItem $targetDir -recurse | where {$_.name -like $pattern} | select name
```

Comment: I didn't read the title correctly and you did. I would include here _why_ your code is the correct solution. just pasting code without context is less than helpful in some cases. `Select-String` is searching file _contents._. You might be able to use `-Filter`  of `Get-ChildItem` as well depending on the nature of pattern and skip the `Where`. The `group` here should be removed as well since those object do not have path properties. .

Comment: The result from doing the above gives an empty result, updated original question with your suggestion

Comment: It really bugs me when people get helpful advice about adding explanations and the response is "Oh, yes thanks, next time I'll do that". No do it now, that's what the edit button is for

Answer (score 11):

To *complement* [Matt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44826242/45375):

Specifically, because **what you're piping to `Select-String` are `[System.IO.FileInfo]` objects** - which is what `Get-ChildItem` outputs - **rather than *strings***, it is the ***contents* of the files represented by these objects is being searched**.

Assuming that you need to match only the *file name* part of each file's path and that your pattern can be expressed as a *wildcard expression*, you do not need `Select-String` at all and can instead use `Get-ChildItem` with `-Filter`, as in Matt's answer, or the slower, but slightly more powerful `-Include`.

*Caveat*:

- `Select-String -Pattern` accepts a *regular expression* (e.g., `.*sample.*`; see `Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`),
- whereas `Get-ChildItem -Filter/-Include` accepts a *wildcard expression* (e.g., `*sample*`; see `Get-Help about_Wildcards`) - they are *different things*.

On a side note: If your intent is to match *files* only, you can tell `Get-ChildItem` to restrict output to files (as opposed to potentially also *directories*) using `-File` (analogously, you can limit output to directories with `-Directory`).

---

`Group-Object path` (`group path`) will not work as intended, because the `.Path` property of the match-information objects output by `Select-String` contains the *full filename*, so you'd be putting each file in its own group - essentially, a no-op.

When using just `Get-ChildItem`, the equivalent property name would be `.FullName`, but what you're looking for is to group by *parent* path (the containing directory's path), `.DirectoryName`), I presume, therefore:

```
... | Group-Object DirectoryName | Select-Object Name
```

This outputs the full path of each *directory* that contains at least 1 file with a matching file name.
(Note that the `Name` in `Select-Object Name` refers to the `.Name` property of the *group* objects returned by `Group-Object`, which in this case is the value of the `.DirectoryName` property on the input objects.)

Answer (score 4):

To complement the excellent answer by @mklement0, you can ask Powershell to print the full path by appending a pipe as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Filter "*sample*" | %{$_.FullName}
```

Note: When searching folders where you might get an error based on security, hence we use the SilentlyContinue option.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the answer by @Itchydon

but couldn't follow the use of '-like' $pattern.

I was trying to list files having 32characters(letters and numbers) in the filename.

PS C:> `Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ -Recurse | where {$_.name -match "[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}"} | select name`

or

PS C:> `Get-ChildItem C:\Users\010M\Documents\WindowsPowerShell -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match "[A-Z0-9]{32}"} | select name`

So, in this case it doesn't matter whether you use **where** or **where-object**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select-string directly to search for files matching a certain string, yes, this will return the filename:count:content ... etc, but, internally these have names that you can chose or omit, the one you need is the "filename" to do this pipe this into "select-object" choosing the "FileName" from the output.

So, to select all *.MSG files that has the pattern of "Subject: Webservices restarted", you can do the following:

> Select-String -Path .*.MSG -Pattern 'Subject: WebServices Restarted'
> -List | select-object Filename

Also, to remove these files on the fly, you could pip into a ForEach statement with the RM command as follows:

> Select-String -Path .*.MSG -Pattern 'Subject: WebServices Restarted'
> -List | select-object Filename | foreach { rm $_.FileName }